# TortoiseSVN reported an error: Can't set position pointer in file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to commit (adding new files) the files into formal trunk folder. Sometimes I get a error message as shown in snapshot below:

[image: Cant set position pointer in file]

The behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes files get committed and sometimes I get this error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This error is reported by your server. There might be several reasons:

- Malfunctioning antivirus application that blocks the commit operation. You must ensure that the antivirus does not touch the repositories and your server. If it does and results in errors, contact your antivirus support and ask them for assistance.
- Missing permissions. Your server must have full access to the location where your repositories are stored.